# Approach to utilize existing css files in sass framework

Tags: css, sass

I've started working on a project that has bunch of css files eg. 15-20 css files which is not the right approach i wanted to use Sass framework but these bunch of css files have confused me. I want to make sure i dont break anything before start writing sass for these css file so wanted to know What's the best strategy i should adapt to integrate sass framework in a project considering we already have bunch of css files??

Answer (score 0):

Valid `css` is valid `sass` so to start you could just change the extension to `.scss` and compile them along with your new sass files. So if you were generating just one `main.css` for example:

```
//main.scss
@import "existing-file-one";
@import "existing-file-two";
@import "existing-file-three";
@import "new-file";
```

This would then add all your existing styles.